# Is there a Vim plugin for previewing markdown files?

Tags: vim, markdown

I love the marked and Mou editor which have the great capability to preview the rendering results on the fly. So I'm wondering, is there a way to do the same thing in Vim?

Comment: This isn't what you're asking for, but if you don't know about it already, checkout [Voom](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657), which is an outliner that works with markdown (`:voom markdown`). It's more useful than an on-the-fly renderer, because it lets you scoot around your document headings.

Comment: All Vim plugins that do this seem to require some external program either Python, Ruby, Javascript or Rust. I prefer [euclio/vim-markdown-composer](https://github.com/euclio/vim-markdown-composer), it's written in Rust in the backend and allows using pandoc as well as a generator. For the most part it just works (requires installing Rust and then a further compile, but works perfectly after doing that an re-starting). It's then *fast* which is the most important thing for me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I recently found a Chrome extension that makes Chrome able to properly open and display markdown files: <s>[Markdown preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview/jmchmkecamhbiokiopfpnfgbidieafmd)</s> (no longer available, you can use [Markdown Preview Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview-plus/febilkbfcbhebfnokafefeacimjdckgl) now).

Then it was just a matter of mapping a key in Vim to open the file with Chrome. Mine looks like this:

```
" Open markdown files with Chrome.
autocmd BufEnter *.md exe 'noremap <F5> :!start C:\Users\tomas\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %:p<CR>'
```

This command would have to be edited, of course, if your files don't have the ".md" extension, you want your mapping on a different key or if Chrome is located at a different location.

Now whenever I'm editing a ".md" file I can hit `<F5>` to open the file in Chrome. A perfect solution would be to get Chrome to auto reload every few seconds, but I can't seem to find an such an extension that works for local files.

---

## Pros:

- The ability to hit a button to preview your markdown file, without the need for any running servers or special code.
- Works on all platforms that supports Vim and Chrome - which pretty much covers all platforms.

## Cons:

- No auto-refresh, you have to hit `<F5>` every time you want to preview the file.
- No Github-flavoured markdown.

Comment: you could mitigate the "no auto-refresh" with a LiveReload extension in Chrome, however, the missing GitHub flavour is a blocker for me.

Comment: @twomm: I can't find such an extension that will work on local files.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei - and check their installation instructions on their site for local files. Did not try it myself, but should work.

Comment: The plugin referenced here now says it uses the Github stylesheet, but I found it lacked support for codeblocks and others.  I had better luck with [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ehnambpmkdhopilaccgfmojilolcglhn)

Comment: Use [Markdown Preview Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-preview-plus/febilkbfcbhebfnokafefeacimjdckgl) instead.

Comment: Tip: Don't forget to allow the markdown plugin to read files in the chrome extensions listing.

Comment: Here is the same command for Mac: autocmd BufEnter *.md exe 'noremap <F5> :! /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome %:p<CR>'

Comment: Is there a way to preview the section of the MD document that changed? I found that if I use autoreload, it takes me to the top of the document, while ithe last reload happend way down..

Comment: Bentley's comment should be added to the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.vim support mathjax

Comment: Late for the party but could anyone please explain what's :p doing here?

Comment: @yatsky `%:p` expands to the full path of the current file. [Documentation reference here.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers)

Answer (score 73):

You're in luck - I've just written a vim plugin with real-time Markdown previewing. It uses github Markdown and styles too: https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown

Comment: I've just stumbled onto your plugin, and like the concept very much. Having some trouble - could you take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321327/porting-a-markdown-live-preview-in-vim-plugin-from-nix-to-windows and tell, could it be made to work on Windows as well?

Comment: It's very cool but unfortunately the editor becomes very laggy and keyboard presses are skipped.

Comment: Really complicated setup, didn't work for me with OSX.

Comment: I love the fact that it opens it automatically, refreshes automatically (even without saving), and closes the preview automatically when I close the file!

Comment: Please let us know when this works with `neovim`!

Comment: @Suan, Thanks. I am thinking of trying it out. When I tried to preview a .md file in my browser using the previously mentioned Google Chrome extension, I have to refresh it. My documents are typically long, not able to fit in a single page. After I refresh the browser, it typically takes me to the top of the md file, while I am editing far away from the top of the .md file. Does you plugin somehow know where the last edit happened, and preview that location in the .md page?

Answer (score 17):

You can actually use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to compile to document format of your choice and view it using external default command. For example i like to preview it as pdf and i use following setup on Ubuntu.

```
" pandoc , markdown
command! -nargs=* RunSilent
      \ | execute ':silent !'.'<args>'
      \ | execute ':redraw!'
nmap <Leader>pc :RunSilent pandoc -o /tmp/vim-pandoc-out.pdf %<CR>
nmap <Leader>pp :RunSilent gnome-open /tmp/vim-pandoc-out.pdf<CR>
```

I compile a document using `,pc` and preview using `,pp`. Since in ubuntu `evince` is default viewer and automatically loads changed files. You end up doing only `,pc` for your changes to reflect.

PS: I have Leader mapped to ,

Comment: I get `E481: No range allowed` trying to compile with this shortcut.

Answer (score 13):

I use [Marked.app](http://markedapp.com/) to preview Markdown files. And have mapped `<leader>p` to do a preview:

```
function! s:setupMarkup()
  nnoremap <leader>p :silent !open -a Marked.app '%:p'<cr>
endfunction

au BufRead,BufNewFile *.{md,markdown,mdown,mkd,mkdn} call s:setupMarkup()
```

If you don't want to drop $4 on Marked.app then you can try [Hammer.vim](https://github.com/wikimatze/hammer.vim). Change the line to:

```
map <buffer> <leader>p :Hammer<CR>
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Codemonkey 's answer, if you are using OSX, you can use the following in your .vimrc file.

```
" Open markdown files with Chrome.
autocmd BufEnter *.md exe 'noremap <F5> :!open -a "Google Chrome.app" %:p<CR>'
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there are several Vim plugins for syntax highlighting, snippets and so on, but ***Vim displays text and text only***, therefore ***you cannot have Markdown*** (or any other kind of) ***preview in Vim***.

If you're interested in real-time preview, maybe [MarkdownPad](http://markdownpad.com/) would suit your needs better.

Comment: Not true, as @Suan has already mentioned there is [vim-instant-markdown](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) which provides live markdown previews for vim. Installation is a bit of a hassel but it works!

Comment: @chutsu: not true: vim-instant-markdown's preview is not within vim but within a browser

Comment: I don't think it was a requirement that the preview *has* to be shown in vim, just that it can be controlled and updated *from* Vim.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple vim plugin to view Markdown in Chrome - it doesn't require ruby or anything fancy and will refresh the preview when you write to the vim buffer (it can also be activated with a hotkey)

Also, the previewing takes place in the background so you never have to leave vim.

https://github.com/JamshedVesuna/vim-markdown-preview

Comment: My documents are typically long, not able to fit in a single page. After I refresh the browser, it typically takes me to the top of the md file, while I am editing far away from the top of the .md file. Does this plugin somehow know where the last edit happened, and preview that location in the .md page?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.vim

Answer (score 1):

I have a function in my .vim dir:

```
function! markdown#preview()
  silent update
  let output_name = tempname() . '.html'

  let file_header = ['<html>', '<head>',
        \ '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">',
        \ '<title>'.expand('%:p').'</title>',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssbase/base-min.css">',
        \ '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssfonts/fonts-min.css">',
        \ '<style>body{padding:20px;}div#container{background-color:#F2F2F2;padding:0 20px;margin:0px;border:solid #D0D0D0 1px;}</style>',
        \ '</head>', '<body>', '<div id="container">']

  call writefile(file_header, output_name)

  silent exec '!markdown "' . expand('%:p') . '" >> "' . output_name . '"'

  silent exec '!echo "</div></body></html>" >> "' . output_name . '"'

  silent exec '!sensible-browser "' . output_name . '" &'
endfunction
```

With that I have the following mapping too:

```
inoremap <buffer> <F7> <ESC>:call markdown#preview()<CR>
nmap <buffer> <F7> :call markdown#preview()<CR>
```

It's not perfect and it's not realtime but it's good enough for my limited needs.

Comment: With it and an automatic reload plugin in a browser, two windows side-by-side...

Comment: @lucapette - That function is basically Nate Silva's plugin stripped down, is it not? http://blog.natesilva.com/

Comment: @Idigas Honestly, I don't remember where I got the function. Although, it's the first time I take a look at that site.

Comment: @lucapette - My bad, I wasn't accusing, just noticing the similarities (the yahoo css caught my eye). A quick question, do you know of a markdown plugin where you can use your own css?

Comment: @Idigas No no. No problem, really. It's just the fact that I don't remember where I got it. BTW, I haven't search it a lot, so I don't know. Perhaps there's room for a plugin...

Answer (score 1):

I came across a nice plugin which worked great out of the box https://github.com/waylan/vim-markdown-extra-preview

Comment: My documents are typically long, not able to fit in a single page. After I refresh the browser, it typically takes me to the top of the md file, while I am editing far away from the top of the .md file. Does this plugin somehow know where the last edit happened, and preview that location in the .md page?

Comment: this is not my plugin, i recommend communicating with the project maintainer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think preview markdown in vim is a good idea.
But you can convert your markdown in HTML just by typing `%!markdown`, presumably you have markdown installed. Then save that file and open it in a browser.