# I cannot open a markdown file name in chinese

Tags: vim, markdown

I follow this post [Is there a vim plugin for preview markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212340/is-there-a-vim-plugin-for-preview-markdown-file) to open a markdown file in chrome. The markdown file name in Chinese (File Name Example:筆記.md).

After I start this file in Chrome. I get a mass URL string "file:///F:/gVimPortable/%E8%9D%91%EF%89%8F%3F.md" in the location bar. The Chrome show me an error information "Your file was not found".
How to fix this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to open a markdown file in Chrome to begin with? It can't do anything useful with it.

Comment: I install a chrome extension "Markdown Preview Plus". It can convert and preview markdown files.

Comment: Where is your md file's location? Is it "F:/gVimPortable/筆記.md"?

Comment: Yes, it is "F:/gVimPortable/筆記.md".